# Some major and minor ticks are not shown in Plotting functions

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am using Mathematica 10.0.1 on Windows 64-bit machine.

I have two 1D lists as follows.

```
list1 = {0.544677,0.43988,0.23622,0.240472,0.208341,2.70294,1.25687,0.208341};
list2 = {0.407358,0.352106,0.195608,0.329957,0.205924,2.35814,1.28687,0.205924};
```

I would like to use `ListPlot` to see their correlation and have the same ticks on both the axis. I use the `Ticks` option in-built in Mathematica, and later also try the `CustomTicks.m`package. Following are the pieces of codes using both methods.

```
maxTick = Max[list1,list2];

ListPlot[Transpose[{list1,list2}], Ticks-> { Range[0,maxTicks,0.5], Range[0,maxTicks,0.5]}, PlotRange->All, AspectRatio->1]
ListPlot[Transpose[{list1,list2}], Ticks-> {LinTicks[0,maxTick], LinTicks[0,maxTick]}, PlotRange->All, AspectRatio->1]
```

Using both methods I do not get the same number of ticks on both the axes. On x-axis the ticks are shown up to a value of `2.7`, but on the y-axis they are shown only up to `2.4`, whereas I would like to have the ticks shown up to a value of `2.7`. Somehow the ticks are limited to the maximum value of the corresponding lists and rounded off for which the tick is shown, i.e. `2.70294` for `list1` on the axis is rounded to `2.7`, and `2.35814` is rounded to `2.4` for `list2`. I have also tried using some of the options in the `LinTicks` from the `CustomTicks.m` package, such as `TicksRange` and `ExtraTicks`. However nothing seems to plot the ticks up to `2.7` on both axes.

Perhaps I am missing something obvious. Could someone please help me getting the same tick marks on both axes? I encountered the same problem for version 10.0.0 too.

Thanks!

P.S: I tried pasting the images here but could not. So please excuse me if my problem is a bit difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
list1 = {0.544677, 0.43988, 0.23622, 0.240472, 0.208341, 2.70294, 1.25687, 0.208341};
list2 = {0.407358, 0.352106, 0.195608, 0.329957, 0.205924, 2.35814, 1.28687, 0.205924};
maxTicks = Max[list1, list2];
```

you can get the desired plot using

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{list1, list2}], Ticks -> {#, #} &@Range[0, maxTicks, 0.5], 
  PlotRange -> {#, #} &@{0, maxTicks + 0.1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

> [image: Plot]

You need to provide the same maximum values for both axes instead of `PlotRange->All`.

Answer (score 1):

Same tick marks on both axes:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{list1, list2}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]